# Create project without storyboard in Xcode 4.3

Tags: xcode, storyboard

If I want to Create project without storyboard in Xcode 4.3
and use only ARC feature from Xcode.

How can we create app without story board as we dont want Navigation controller,
in app and use addsubview as we use to code in earlier versions.

Does app coded in Xcode 4.3 can be deployed on iOS 4.0 ,iOS 4.3, or only works with iOS 5

Please let me know..

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To my strong dismay, Apple removed the "Use Storyboards" checkbox in Xcode 5. Every project gets created with a dreaded UIStoryboard. I wrote a tool that converts Xcode 4's project templates to Xcode 5, so you can once again create projects with or without storyboards. You can find it here on GitHub: https://github.com/jfahrenkrug/Xcode4templates

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new project there is an option to "Use Storyboards". Don't tick that.

Do tick the "Use Automatic Reference Counting" box.

Apps developed in Xcode 4.3 can target platforms below 5.0, it's up to you to ensure that you include / exclude the appropriate features.